# How do I change the color of my alien's feces?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, biochemistry

I apologise in advance for the graphic nature of this question. I guess it just had to be asked.

I am looking for a way to make the feces of my alien vertebrates some color other than brown or green. In our Terran vertabrates, bile that is broken down in the gut along with items in the diet affect the color of fecal matter. We usually see green, rust, or the 'classic' brown unless something unusual such as a beet was eaten. My first thought when finding an answer to this question was to find an alternative to bile for breaking down fats into fatty acids. I am looking for something that would change the color almost regardless of what was eaten, as bile does.  Anything that would change the color in carnivores, herbivores and everything in between would work. As long as the feces will be distinguishable from Terran feces, it should work.

Thanks for bearing with this one.

Comment: I feel sorry for whoever is going to go through the comments on this one . . . .

Comment: @FoxElemental Me too

Comment: Are you asking if the feces will be a different color when beheld (ugh) here upon Earth?  Or do we have the wavelength of an alien sun and the chemical composition of alien sky and soil to deal with?  (If it makes you feel any better, this isn't the most disgusting question asked here... not by a long shot....)

Comment: @JBH Assume that the atmospheric conditions on the alien planet and the soil compositions are extremely similar to those on Earth. The sun that planet is orbiting is the same as the sun on Earth. So, if the alien were in either world, the feces would look the same.

Comment: @Aify Many bird droppings are actually very dark brown or green along with their white urate.

Comment: Case in point: There's white.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have a species that essentially empties it's stomach acid as part of the digestive system, you'd get yellowish-orange (vomit) color.

Comment: This really has a lot to do with what you eat.  Blueberries make feces blue.  Black licorice icecream (whatever is actually in it) makes it green.  I don't even want to think about what makes it yellow.  However, giving you a biological breakdown of what chemicals need to be in your aliens for sundry colors is too broad.  What color are you looking for?

Comment: @JBH I'm looking for something like purple, blue, perhaps red. I would like to find a way that the creatures' metabolism gives the feces the color almost regardless of what they eat. As an example, humans have brown feces and even if they eat a few blueberries, the feces will still appear somewhat brown. It is not until a human eats a large number of blueberries when the feces turn purple or blue. (I can't believe I'm trying to find a feces color like a car or wall color.)

Answer (score 8):

**Bone = white dung.**

If an animal eats a lot of bones, much of the bone minerals is not digested.  It passes through into the feces and turns them white.  I have seen this with dog droppings. Hyaenas routinely eat bones; depicted are hyaena droppings.

[image: hyaena droppings]
https://thomsonsafaris.com/blog/identify-animal-scat-walking-safari/

---

Another way to get white feces is how reptiles do it: concentrate the nitrogenous wastes that mammals pass as urine, and pass that concentrate as feces.  The nitrogenous waste (mostly urea) is a white substance with the regular poop brown.  Reptile feces is bicolor for this reason.

[image: snake poop]

http://www.feedpecker.com/snake-poop-look-like/

Comment: With pictures?  Sigh.

Comment: goodbye Oreo, it was nice until it lasted...

Comment: Dogs also used to leave white dung, but we now feed them very rich food so it's less common. It's not about the bone it's about their ability to be wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

**Blue dung (or purple or red)**

If you can design the metabolism of your aliens to excrete *anthocyanin* (an organic pigment) you could have a reason for their poop to be blue, purple or red (depending on the PH of the remaining components of the dung). So, the same way we humans have a variety of standard colors, they could have their own pantone (depending on what they have eaten).
More info about the anthocyanin in this Wikipedia link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthocyanin

Answer (score -1):

Their normal gut flora includes something that releases a chemical that is whatever color you want.

Comment: could you add some concrete example?